# launch an activity using intent and disable back button press from launching the previous activity

Tags: android, back-button, android-intent

In my application. I have a `login` screen. If the login is successful, a `tab activity` will launch, in that there are 4 tabs. When I press one of the buttons in the tab, a new activity will launch. there is an event in my `login` class that will get fired in some cases. I want to go back to the tab activity when the event get fired. I have written a code using Intent. That code is working fine. But after reaching the tab activity I don't want to go back to the activity when back button is pressed. I want to remove this. I want to show login when Back is  pressed. Is there any way to do this? This is the code I have used:

```
Intent tabi=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tab.class);
startActivity(tabi);
```

The code `onkeydown` in tab activity is:

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you can call finish() on your activity on back press..

Answer (score 11):

```
Intent tabi=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tab.class);
            startActivity(tabi);
finish();
```

Comment: hey if my answers is right than plz mark as right answers

Answer (score 7):

Just call finish(); method after starting the activity. It will prevent from back button

Like:

```
Intent tabi=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tab.class);
startActivity(tabi);
finish();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

use **onBackPressed** and in that start Your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
   Intent intent = new Intent(Tab.this , Login.class);
   startActivity(intent)
}
```

and you can clear the history with bellow code that user can't came back from login Page to visited Page

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 2):

When event get fired, call tab activity with these intent flags

```
Intent tabi=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tab.class);
tabi.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(tabi);
```

Answer (score 1):

Going back to login screen, can be achieved in two ways:

First way is, (assuming you are currently on login scren) to simply navigate to the next activity using `Intent`, without finishing the current activity, and inside `onBackPressed()` you simply need to call `finish()`.

Second way is, if you `finish()` the login activity, then simply navigate to `login` activity using `Intent` and finish the tab activity.

Its simple. Use Intent to go to login screen:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
    finish();

    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```